# RGB pixel transparency

Tags: c++, image

I am combining two RGB images, pixel by pixel, each of different sizes, while combining them I'd like the one that is on top, which is smaller in size to be transparent regarding two the bigger one in the background, like a see-through. What processing should I do? Cause right now..merging the images resumes just to replacing pixels. How can I achieve this transparency? I'm using c++.

Comment: well basically it's `newColor = ColorTop * alpha + ColorBottom *(1-alpha)` ,where alpha is the opaqueness value between 0 and 1. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Have you tried giving the images a weight factor? if you do the smaller image * 0.5 + big image * 1.0 and divide it by the total weight you might end up with a see-through image

Comment: The term you are looking for is alpha blending. Each channel in the color (RGB) is mixed proportionially based on the proportions of the Alpha Channel in each pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the basic formula for blending two images is `newColor = ColorTop * alpha + ColorBottom * (1-alpha)`.

Some images contain an alpha value per pixel, but from your brief description this doesn't sound like the case you're interested in. You just want a constant transparency applied to the entire upper image. Let's assume you want 33% transparency for example:

```
alpha = 0.33
Rnew = (Rtop * alpha) + (Rbottom * (1.0 - alpha))
Gnew = (Gtop * alpha) + (Gbottom * (1.0 - alpha))
Bnew = (Btop * alpha) + (Bbottom * (1.0 - alpha))
```

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer, it is exactly what I was looking for.